# Visual Basic - Nested IF in IIF with OrElse

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reportbuilder

I have an expression in Visual Basic that came out of SQL Report Builder I am trying to modify.  I am getting up to speed on all things SQL as it is all new for me, and I am still learning the proper structure and syntax.

What I am trying to do is modify the expression to take the output from DonationAmount and see if it is >= to 10, if it is <10 then I want "10" to populate rather than the lesser amount.  Here is the code:

```
=Iif(
    Fields!ndpPP.Value = 1,
    "",
    Iif(
        Fields!IsCP.Value = 1,
        "Text 1 " & Iif(
            Fields!IsS.Value OrElse 
            Fields!IsProbation.Value OrElse 
            Fields!UnfilteredRateTypeID.Value = 9  
            OrElse Fields!UnfilteredRateTypeID.Value = 10, 
            "",
            " " & Format(Fields!DonationAmount.Value, "C0") & ""
        ) & " Text 3",
        "Text 2 " & Iif(
            Fields!IsS.Value OrElse 
            Fields!IsProbation.Value OrElse
            Fields!UnfilteredRateTypeID.Value = 9 OrElse
            Fields!UnfilteredRateTypeID.Value = 10,
            "",
            " " & Format(Fields!DonationAmount.Value, "C0") & ""
        ) & " Text 4"
    )
)
```

Comment: You shoud change the `Iif`s to the [`If` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator). Which amounts to removing one "i" from "Iif".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (once you integrate it into the rest of the expression)

```
Iif(Fields!DonationAmount.Value < 10, 10, Fields!DonationAmount.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you Tomalak!  Both answers here will help longterm.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose `Iif` over the `If` function?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Mainly because the OP has been using `Iif` in the existing code.

Comment: We ultimately went with the nested IIF statement in Report Builder.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the output from

```
Format(Fields!DonationAmount.Value, "C0")
```

to something like

```
Format(math.Max(Fields!DonationAmount.Value, 10), "C0")
```

That will print the value or 10, whichever is the greater

Comment: Thank you Jon!  I think this will be the easiest longterm.